# Playframework Java application, saving user details into Couchbase database

Tags: java, couchdb

I am creating back-end for a web-application in Play framework with Java, using Couchbase for storage. This class is saving and fetching `User` details from Couchbase.

My questions are:

- Will my DAO implementation work for high volume traffic (thousands of users saving and fetching User details simultaneously)? If not, how can I handle huge traffic?
- How can it be optimized?

**Project details:**

- scalaVersion: "2.12.4"
- "com.couchbase.client" % "java-client" % "2.4.2"

**Code files:**

`AppDaoService` interface:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import com.google.inject.ImplementedBy;

@ImplementedBy(AppDaoServiceImpl.class)
public interface AppDaoService {

    public void storeUserData(User user);

    public CompletionStage<User> getUserData(String userCode);

}
```

`AppDaoServiceImpl` class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket;
import com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.JsonDocument;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject;
import com.couchbase.client.java.env.CouchbaseEnvironment;
import com.couchbase.client.java.env.DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.marriott.exceptions.DataNotFoundException;
import com.marriott.exceptions.InternalServerException;
import com.typesafe.config.Config;

import play.Logger;
import play.Logger.ALogger;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecutionContext;

public class AppDaoServiceImpl implements AppDaoService {

    private static final ALogger logger = Logger.of(AppDaoServiceImpl.class);
    private final HttpExecutionContext ec;

    private final Config config;
    private Cluster cluster = null;
    private Bucket bucket = null;
    private CouchbaseEnvironment env;

    @Inject
    public AppDaoServiceImpl(final HttpExecutionContext ec, Config config) {
        this.config = config;
        this.ec = ec;
        env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().build();
        cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env, config.getString("couchbase.url"));
    }

    @Override
    public void storeUserData(User user) {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                bucket = cluster.openBucket(config.getString("couchbase.bucket.name"),
                        config.getString("couchbase.bucket.password"));

                logger.info("Storing user for userCode: " + user.getUserCode());

                String documentId = user.getUserCode() + "_user";
                JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.fromJson(Json.toJson(user).toString());

                bucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create(documentId, jsonObject));
                logger.info("Successfully stored userCode: " + user.getUserCode());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Storing userCode: " + user.getUserCode() + " unsuccessful");
                throw new InternalServerException(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                if (!bucket.isClosed()) {
                    bucket.close();
                }
            }
        }, ec.current()).join();
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<User> getUserData(String userCode) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                bucket = cluster.openBucket(config.getString("couchbase.bucket.name"),
                        config.getString("couchbase.bucket.password"));

                logger.info("Fetching user data for userCode:" + userCode);

                String documentID = userCode + "_user";
                JsonDocument retrievedJsonDocument = bucket.get(documentID);

                if (retrievedJsonDocument != null) {
                    JsonNode json = Json.parse(retrievedJsonDocument.content().toString());
                    User userData = Json.fromJson(json, User.class);
                    logger.info("Successfully fetched userCode: " + userCode);
                    return userData;
                } else {
                    logger.error("Fetching userCode:" + userCode + " unsuccessful");
                    throw new DataNotFoundException("User data not found for userCode: " + userCode);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            } finally {
                if (!bucket.isClosed()) {
                    bucket.close();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`User` model class:

````
public class User {

    private String userCode;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String pinCode;

    public User(String userCode, String firstName, String lastName, String pinCode) {
        super();
        this.userCode = userCode;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
    }

    public String getUserCode() {
        return userCode;
    }

    public void setUserCode(String userCode) {
        this.userCode = userCode;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPinCode() {
        return pinCode;
    }

    public void setPinCode(String pinCode) {
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
    }

}

```
````

Comment: This is tagged incorrectly. CouchDB is not Couchbase. I don't have enough reputation here to create a new tag.